# php - filter_input - set to default value if GET key not set

Tags: php, get, filter-input

I'd like to have a clean, elegant way to set a variable to a GET parameter if said parameter is set (and numeric), and to 0 (or some other default) if it's not set.

Right now I have:

```
if (($get_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))) {
    $opened_staff['id'] = $get_id;
    // some database queries etc.
} else { $opened_staff['id'] = 0; }
```

I tried using a callback function that returns 0 if the value is null or not numeric, but if the GET parameter 'id' isn't set, the callback won't even be called - it just sets `$get_id` to null.

Not a big deal to include the else statement, just thought I might be missing out on some functionality of `filter_input`.

Comment: Give me some more clear explanation

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function accepts an `options` parameter. Each filter accepts different options. For example, the `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` filter can accept `default`, `min_range` and `max_range` options [as described here](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

```
$get_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array(
    "default" => 0,
    "min_range" => 0
)));
var_dump($get_id);

// $get_id = 0 when id is not present in query string, not an integer or negative
// $get_id = <that integer> otherwise
```

Comment: bingo. That's the thing I was missing. default key in the options array. Thanks!

Comment: If you also need to add other flags, they should be in the `flags` key. For example `array("options" => array("default" => []), "flags" => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use default option to achieve this, If value not set then default value will get assign, example as given below

```
$options = array( 'options' => array('default'=> 0) ); 
$valid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options);
```

filter_input() doesn't read from the _POST/_GET/_COOKIE/_SERVER/_ENV

```
$opened_staff['id'] = 0;
if($valid){
  $opened_staff['id'] = $_GET['id'];
}
```

You can use some class to achieve this. [NOTE:- *this is just an example*]

```
class RequestFilter{
 public static function get_filter_int($id){

   $options = array( 'options' => array('default'=> 0) ); 
   $valid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options); 

   if($valid){
     return $_GET[$id]; // Value will return
   }

   return $valid; // Default will return
 }
}

$opened_staff['id'] = RequestFilter::get_filter_int('id');
```

here will return value or default, here it is zero.

Comment: Why not simply return `$valid` in your if-statement since you've already extracted the valid value in this case, or is there a reason I'm missing?(relatively new to PHP)

Comment: You don't need the if at all, if valid is "true" then you return `$_GET[$id]` which is the same as `$valid` because filter_input return the value if it is valid. In the else case you return `$valid`. So you are return always the same as `$valid`.